# How do i create a custom devcontainer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

i have been using devcontainers for a while, and i want to extend some of them.
For instance, i want to install all the linting tools etc for various languages, and use a more personalised container as a starting point (compared to the Microsoft hosted ones).

I also like to host the containers on my own dockerhub, so i do not need to build all this stuff every time. There could also be the use case of using devcontainers for something other than the standard libraries.

I know i can just manually change the docker image reference, but i also like to integrate my changes into the plugin, so i can have my own repository show up as well, to get a native feeling.

I could not find any information on creating my own dev containers, only on extending existing ones. Is any of this i mention officially supported?

Edit: To sum all this up in one question; Can i add devcontainers from my own repo, without merging them into https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers ?

Comment: yes you can start from scratch, look at https://containers.dev/guide/dockerfile However, it is a bit painful to get vscode to interact with a custom built container image because it requires some tools like git and ssh to be installed in the container and makes some assumptions about users in the container. Maybe you are better off looking at how they did it with an example: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/alpine https://github.com/devcontainers/images/tree/main/src/base-alpine The other mechanism besides Docker that you will need to understand is .devcont' "features".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCode as the text editor you can install the [remote extension pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack&WT.mc_id=academic-0000-alfredodeza) which allows you to add a template for a devcontainer to your project.

[image: VSCode showing option for Dev Container]

If you aren't using VSCode you can use the templated version as the basis for your own. I created a *template* [repository with the files needed for Python project](https://github.com/alfredodeza/devcontainer-python-template) which you can refer to as well